# Php page not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

I am having a problem displaying a JOIN statement. When I add

```
 WHERE id = " . $team_id;
```

The information that is on the database will not display, but when I remove that line the information will correctly join and display on the "teaminfo.php " page, but it will display all of the data instead of the data that is unique to that id. Also when I remove the JOIN the the data that is unique to the id will display. Can anyone tell me whats wrong here. Any help will be great. Than you.

teaminfo.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Team Info page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    include 'connect.php';
$team_id = $_GET['id'];

// SQL query
$query = " SELECT *
FROM pitscouting 
JOIN fieldscouting 
ON pteam_number = fteam_number
WHERE id = " . $team_id;


if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   // Write the data of the team
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Pit scouting";
    echo "<dt>Team:</dt><dd>" . $row["pteam_number"] . " " . $row["pteam_name"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Auto:</dt><dd>" . $row["pauto"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Drive:</dt><dd>" . $row["pdrive"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Objetcs With No Problem?</dt><dd>" . $row["pobjNoProblem"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Objects They have a problem with?</dt><dd>" . $row["pobjWithProblem"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Can they shoot? If yes from where and how acc</dt><dd>" . $row["pshoot"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Extra Notes about their robot?</dt><dd>" . $row["pdrive"] . "</dd>";

    echo"<br />";

    echo "Field Scouting ";
    echo "<dt>Team Number:</dt><dd>" . $row["fteam_number"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Auto:</dt><dd>" . $row["fauto"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Drive:</dt><dd>" . $row["fdrive"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Objetcs With No Problem?</dt><dd>" . $row["fobjNoProblem"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Objects They have a problem with?</dt><dd>" . $row["fobjWithProblem"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Shots taken</dt><dd>" . $row["fshots_taken"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Shorts made</dt><dd>" . $row["fshots_made"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Extra Notes</dt><dd>" . $row["fnotes"] . "</dd>";


  }

  mysqli_free_result($result);

 }


// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>


<p><a href="palmetto.php">Return to the list</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Palmetto.php

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

// SQL query
$query = "SELECT * FROM pitscouting ORDER BY pteam_number";

if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $name = $row['pteam_number'] . " " . $row['pteam_name'];

        // Create a link to teaminfo.php with the id-value in the URL
   $strLink = "<a href = 'teaminfo.php?id= " . $row['id'] . "'>" . $name . "</a>";

    // List link
   echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    // Close result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
  } else{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
   }
// Close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: I'll bet both tables have an `id` column. You need to use `WHERE tablename.id =` to specify which table's ID you want to check.

Comment: And if you had the error checking that @Fred-ii- recommended, you would have seen an error message that told you that the column name is ambiguous.

Comment: You should also use a prepared query with `bind_param` instead of concatenating variables into the query, to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: The `teaminfo.php` code has no `else` action when the call to `mysqli_query` evaluates to FALSE, when a MySQL error occurs. The code is putting it's pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr.Evil style "I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?". And it's going to be easy to make a SQL error occur, given the SQL Injection vulnerability. If the intent is to "do nothing" when an error occurs, IMO the code should have an `else` and at least have a comment that the code is going to ignore the error.

Comment: This question might be better titled **"Php page ignoring error returned by mysqli_query"**, and ask "How can the page find out what the error was?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables both have an ID field you will have to specify which table you want to get the data from.

```
WHERE pitscouting.id = " . $team_id;
```

or

```
WHERE fieldscouting.id = " . $team_id;
```

Comment: you mean `WHERE pitscouting.id = `

Comment: It worked, Thank you very much for you help. Have a great day.  @Beans

Comment: I'm glad. Could you set my answer as the correct one then? @kaydrae

Answer (score 0):

Please do mention the sql injection in you're code

```
$team_id = $_GET['id'];

// SQL query
$query = " SELECT *
FROM pitscouting 
JOIN fieldscouting 
ON pteam_number = fteam_number
WHERE id = " . $team_id;
```

please take a look at prepared statements, to prevent sql injections in youre code

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an alias.

```
$team_id = $_GET['id'];

// SQL query
$query = " SELECT *
FROM pitscouting p
JOIN fieldscouting f
ON p.pteam_number = f.fteam_number
WHERE p1.id = " . $team_id;
```